# Is there case for closed paragraphs tags <p/>

Tags: html

I'm reading HTML Paragraphs documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

but there is nothing about `<p/>` usage

But I was trying it and it works as new line. Is there difference between `p` and `br` in this case?

If I can use `<p/>` as `<br/>` then why do I need `<br/>` ?

Comment: It's `</p>` not `<p/>`.

Comment: @markus I mean exactly `<p/>`

Comment: @Наташа please see my answer, then.

Comment: Doesn't exist because you're not supposed to have empty paragraphs.

Comment: @markus but it works as new line or something very similar

Comment: It's not valid HTML, you will get: Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Comment: @markus where I will get it? (I was trying on Firefox)

Comment: When you validate your HTML. Try any existing HTML validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>` elements are paragraphs, they are not empty elements and cannot be self-closed (i.e. `<p/>` is not valid). They **must** contain some other nodes, and should be correctly closed using `</p>`, for example:

```
<p>This is my paragraph</p>
```

A `<br />` tag is an empty element (i.e. it cannot contain child elements).

Empty `<p>` elements are strongly discouraged in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1), for example:

> The `P` element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including `P` itself).
>
> We discourage authors from using empty `P` elements. User agents
>   should ignore empty `P` elements.

What is actually happening is that your browser is converting your invalid `<p/>` to `<p></p>`, and then displaying an empty paragraph. Browsers have some default CSS rules for elements defined, and since `<p>` elements are block-level elements with a default margin defined, this explains why you seem to see a 'new line' when using `<p />`.

If you use a CSS reset, such as:

```
p {
    margin: 0
}
```

You will see the 'new line' disappear. This is why `<br />` exists. It allows you to force a line break within HTML.

Comment: But they're not *valid*, there's a big difference between what 'works', and what should be done / is valid.

Comment: what means valid in this terms?

Comment: @Наташа what is defined the specification for HTML, for example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/, more specifically: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Comment: I think it's just synonymic to `<p></p>` and how could that be not valid?

Comment: No, `<p />` is not synonymous with a fully-qualified element. Just because a closing tag is *optional* does not mean the element can self-close itself.

Comment: `User agents should ignore empty P elements.` - does it mean that browser lie to me when puts new line with empty p?

Comment: No. It's the browser trying to repair your HTML for you. Most browsers do *not* ignore empty `<p>` elements. What's happening is that your browser is actually converting `<p />` into `<p></p>`, and then displaying it as an empty paragraph.

Comment: This is the problem with W3 Schools. `:empty` is a pseudo-selector that works independently of the HTML spec. Their example is a little misleading, it might have been better for them to use `div:empty`.

Comment: thanks, I understood now, should I avoid W3 Schools? :)

Comment: @Natasha Yes, almost certainly. MDN is a great, accurate resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` stands for Line break and it sends your text to the next line.

`<p>` stands for paragraph. It creates a blank line and then move to a new line.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. `<p>` does not create any blank lines or modify the text in any way. It simply achieves the appearance of spacing through CSS. It may appear to create a blank line, but that is because `<p>` is a block-level element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `<br/>` it's a relic from the old web, generally you should avoid using it unless you're building something like an email. `<br/>` tags makes responsive styling on websites harder, you can do everything with CSS instead nowadays.

The closing  tag acts in a similar way since it breaks the following content on to the next line.